# HTTP Verb at ServiceStack Service and at DTO routing

Tags: servicestack

I am newbie to ServiceStack.  From the [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Your-first-webservice-explained), the Service class has the Any, Get..etc HTTP Verb functions to get the DTO object.   The DTO [routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) can have the HTTP Verb to limit to routing.  How does these Service and DTO routing work together OR do these two HTTP Verb limit much match?

e.g if the service has only the Get function, but the DTO has the Put limit, does it mean no routing will match?

```
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Get(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}

[Route("/hello/{Name}", "PUT")]
public class Hello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where can I find more information about these?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Custom Routing and Service implementation access are decoupled. The Routing defines what Custom Routes can be used to call your Service whilst your Service implementation defines what Requests your Service can handle.

Note: Your Services is not limited to and can be called outside of your Custom routes, e.g. when using [Pre-defined Routes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#pre-defined-routes), or [Messaging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging), [Service Gateway](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-Gateway), etc.

So your Routes defintions define what Custom Route it allows, where:

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}", "PUT")]
```

Only matches a `PUT` Request starting with `/hello`, e.g:

```
 PUT /hello/foo
```

But if someone makes a `PUT /hello/foo` Request ServiceStack will throw a Not Implemented Exception because it wont be able to find a method implementation that can handle that request which for a PUT Request needs to be either:

```
public object Put(Hello request) { ... }
```

Or the `Any()` fallback which can handle the Request on **ANY** HTTP Verbs:

```
public object Any(Hello request) { ... }
```

Unless you have multiple implementations for the same Request DTO, I'd recommend sticking to implementing your Services with `Any()`, e.g:

```
public object Any(Hello request) { ... }
```

That way your Custom Routes can limit what routes are allowed and when a Request matches it will call the best matching implementation or fallback to the `Any()` implementation.